# What should be the growing medium for Sansevieria plant

Tags: plant-care, growing-medium, snake-plants

I have few sansevieria plants that need to be placed in the rooms. I want to know what kind of soil/growing medium is best for this plant. Some says, growing medium should be like cactus or succulents. Please advise